# static / singleton / something similar?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I dont have much experience in  OOP / Design patterns and below is my question.

I want to use a value of a string-variable in all my Visual Studio Projects in a solution.
ie., I create a variable called strVar in one of my C# project. and all the other projects have reference to it.

Actually what I want is - the value of the string-variable has to be computed - once the  Dll is loaded (or first time I access the Class.Variable) and not every time I access that variable.

[When the class is accessed for the First time - I want the value to be computed and stay - throught the lifecycle of the Dll / App domain. ]

ie.,   the string value will be different in each installation of the application - and cant use .config file.

Is there a way to accomplish this ??

Comment: Do you need the string to be the same every time you run a particular installation of the application?

Answer (score 2):

```
public SomePubliclyVisibleClass
{
  private static _strVal = ComputedStrVal();//we could have a public field, but 
                                            //since there are some things that
                                            //we can do with a property that we
                                            //can't with a field and it's a breaking
                                            //change to change from one to the other
                                            //we'll have a private field and
                                            //expose it through a public property
  public static StrVal
  {
    get { return _strVal; }
  }
  private static string ComputedStrVal()
  {
    //code to calculate and return the value
    //goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

For example...

```
public class ImportantData
{
    public static string A_BIG_STRING;

    // This is your "static constructor"
    static ImportantData()
    {
        A_BIG_STRING = CalculateBigString();
    }

    private static string CalculateBigString()
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

As the documentation say, amongst other things, the static constructor holds this property:

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Static constructors is the answer. One time initialization ( when you first access class ), just what you need. Do your initialization in static constructor.